A Trace inequality

For $A,B$ positive self-adjoint matrices do we have $$\operatorname{tr}(AB^2A) \leq \|A\|\|B\|\operatorname{tr}(BA),$$ where $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the operator norm, and $\operatorname{tr}$ denotes the Trace.

Note that the result could be rephrased as $\|AB\|_{HS}^2 \leq \|A\|\|B\|\operatorname{tr}(BA)$, where HS denotes the Hilbert-Scmidt norm (i.e. the Frobenius norm when we deal with matrices).

There is a lot of extraneous stuff here. What about the inequality $\text{tr}(CDj\le |C|\text{tr}(D)$ with your hypotheses?

Hi Ted, I have seen this inequality for $C$ and $D$ positive, symmetric. But applying this to $C = AB$ and $D=BA$ would fail to satisfy those hypothesis.

Ah, good point. No idea.

Clearly, equality holds when $A=0$ or $B=0$. When $A,B\ne0$, let $X=A/\|A\|,\,Y=B/\|B\|$. Then $X\succeq X^2$ and $Y\succeq Y^2$ because $\|X\|=\|Y\|=1$. Therefore
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{tr}(YX)-\operatorname{tr}(XY^2X)
&=\operatorname{tr}(XY-X^2Y^2)\\
&=\operatorname{tr}\left(X(Y-Y^2)+(X-X^2)Y^2\right)\\
&=\operatorname{tr}\left(X^{1/2}(Y-Y^2)X^{1/2}+Y(X-X^2)Y\right)\\
&\ge0
\end{align*}
and the result follows.
